# Can the jordan canonical form be $[0]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $$M=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 0 & 4 & 3 \\  3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1& 2  \\ \end{bmatrix}\in(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{5Z})$$

I want to prove that this matrix has a Jordan canonical form and find it. When I try to calculate it, I have that the characteristic polynomial is $x^4$ and the minimal polynomial $x$, so the Jordan canonical form must be

$$J=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0& 0  \\ \end{bmatrix}\in(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{5Z})$$
Is this correct?

Comment: The minimal polynomial can't possibly be $x$. That would imply that $M = 0$, which is clearly not the case. I believe the minimal polynomial is $x^2$.

Comment: The minimal polynomial for a matrix needn't be irreducible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Jordan form of a non-zero matrix cannot possibly be zero.  Note that for any invertible $S$, $S0S^{-1} = 0$.  So, the only matrix similar to the zero matrix is the zero-matrix itself (a similar phenomenon occurs with the multiples of the identity matrix).

Note that the minimal polynomial of this matrix is actually $x^2$.  In this case, the minimal polynomial is not sufficient to determine the Jordan form.  It suffices, however, to note that $M$ has minimal polynomial $x^2$ **and** rank at least $2$.  We can thereby deduce that the Jordan form is 
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&1\\&0\\&&0&1\\&&&0}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understood it. I believe you made a typo mistake and the last $0$ of the matrix $J$ shouldn't be there. Also, If I wanted to calculate the matrix $S\in{\mathbb{(Z/5Z)}}$, how could I do it? Usually I would calculate the vectors of $Ker(M-0Id)$ and $Ker(M-0Id)^2$, but in this case, when I solve $M*(x,y,z,t)^t=0$ and $M^2*(x,y,z,t)^t=0$ I have that $Ker(M^2-0Id)=\mathbb{R^4}$ and $Ker(M-0Id)=0$. I don't know how to work with that results.

Comment: You're right about the typo.  What you need to use are "chains of generalized eigenvectors".  Try googling that, see if you can make sense of the results.  The process is a bit too involved to explain in a comment